# Azure DevOps and Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have the Azure DevOps organization called "Pay4it", which i want to connect to Azure Active Directory - I have treid to click "Connect directory", and a new window open and a error comes op: 
*We cannot find your account(jt@rc-pay4it.dk) in any Azure Active Directory. Please talk to the administrator of your company's Azure Active Directory to get your user account(jt@rc-pay4it.dk) added to that directory.*

If i try to login into portal.azure.com with the username jt@rc-pay4it.dk it works fine, but still i have no Azure Active Directories in the dropdown.

I can't figure out what i'm missing, hopefully someone knows what i'm doing wrong.

I have attached a picture that shows the setup, the user created in Azure AD and that the user is owner of the organization in DevOps

[image: The picture that shows the setup and the created user in Azure AD]

Comment: i think when you login to Azure Devops you should get a prompt to choose between work or personal account, try using work account

Comment: When i log into Azure DevOps it is a work account, created in Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

The user who makes the connection must confirm the following statements are true.

- User exists in Azure AD as a member. If the user is an Azure AD
  guest, rather than member
- User is a project collection administrator or owner of the
  organization
- User isn't using the Microsoft account identity that matches the
  Azure AD identity. For example, if the Microsoft account that users
  are currently using is jamalhartnett@fabrikam.com, the Azure AD
  identity they'll use after connecting is also
  jamalhartnett@fabrikam.com. Use a single identity that spans both
  applications, rather than two separate identities using the same
  email.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops#prerequisites

Comment: I have made sure that the user is an Azure AD member and not a guest.

I made sure that the user is the owner of the organization.

And the user is not a Microsoft account.

The picture shows it here: https://imgur.com/a/NWQklxG - But yet i cant add any?

Comment: And you are Project Collection admin or owner? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/lookup-organization-owner-admin?view=azure-devops

Comment: I am both - I have added my self in these groups:
Project Collection Administrators
Project Collection Build Administrators
Project Collection Build Service Accounts

Comment: If i create a new DevOps site, called Pay4itTest, then it works fine, i can connect it to Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Sounds weird, I would open a Microsoft case since you went through all pre-read and other projects works fine.